# string replace using dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, replace

I am using the below function to replace a sub-string in a given string

```
void ReplaceSubStr(char **inputString, const char *from, const char *to)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    int i, cnt = 0;
    int tolen = strlen(to);
    int fromlen = strlen(from);

    if (*inputString == NULL)
        return;

    // Counting the number of times old word
    // occur in the string
    for (i = 0; (*inputString)[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (strstr((&(*inputString)[i]), from) == &(*inputString)[i])
        {
            cnt++;

            // Jumping to index after the old word.
            i += fromlen - 1;
        }
    }

    // Making new string of enough length
    result = (char *)malloc(i + cnt * (tolen - fromlen) + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return;

    memset(result, 0, i + cnt * (tolen - fromlen) + 1);

    i = 0;
    while (&(*inputString))
    {
        // compare the substring with the result
        if (strstr(*inputString, from) == *inputString)
        {
            strncpy(&result[i], to, strlen(to));
            i += tolen;
            *inputString += fromlen;
        }
        else
        {
            result[i++] = (*inputString)[0];
            if ((*inputString)[1] == '\0')
                break;
            *inputString += 1;
        }
    }

    result[i] = '\0';
    *inputString = result;
    return;
}
```

The problem with the above function is memory leak. Whatever memory is allocated for inputString will be lost after this line.

```
*inputString = result;
```

since I am using strstr and moving pointer of inputString `*inputString += fromlen;` inputString  is pointing to NULL before the above line. So how to handle memory leak here.

Note: I dont want to return the new memory allocated inside the function. I need to alter the inputString memory based on new length.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a local variable to iterate over the input string and avoid modifying `*inputString` before the final step where you free the previous string and replace it with the newly allocated pointer.

With the current API, `ReplaceSubStr` must be called with the address of a pointer to a block allocated with `malloc()` or similar. Passing a pointer to local storage or a string literal will have undefined behavior.

Here are a few ideas for improvement:

- you could return the new string and leave it to the caller to free the previous one. In this case, you would take the input string by value instead of by address:

  ```
  char *ReplaceSubStr(const char *inputString, const char *from, const char *to);
  ```
- If the `from` string is empty, you should either insert the `to` string between each character of the input string or do nothing. As posted, your code has undefined behavior for this border case.
- To check if the `from` string is present at offset `i`, use `memcmp` instead of `strstr`.
- If `cnt` is 0, there is nothing to do.
- You should return an error status for the caller to determine if memory could be allocated or not.
- There is no need to initialize the `result` array.
- avoid using `strncpy()`. This function has counter-intuitive semantics and is very often misused. Read this: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ReplaceSubStr(char **inputString, const char *from, const char *to) {
    char *input = *inputString;
    char *p, *q, *result;
    size_t cnt;
    size_t tolen = strlen(to);
    size_t fromlen = strlen(from);

    if (input == NULL || fromlen == 0)
        return 0;

    // Counting the number of times old word occurs in the string
    for (cnt = 0, p = input; (p = strstr(p, from)) != NULL; cnt++) {
        p += fromlen;
    }
    if (cnt == 0)   // no occurrence, nothing to do.
        return 0;

    // Making new string of enough length
    result = (char *)malloc(strlen(input) + cnt * (tolen - fromlen) + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return -1;

    for (p = input, q = result;;) {
        char *p0 = p;
        p = strstr(p, from);
        if (p == NULL) {
            strcpy(q, p0);
            break;
        }
        memcpy(q, p0, p - p0);
        q += p - p0;
        memcpy(q, to, tolen);
        q += tolen;
        p += fromlen;
    }
    free(*inputString);
    *inputString = result;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char *p = strdup("Hello world!");
    ReplaceSubStr(&p, "l", "");
    printf("%s\n", p);  // prints Heo word!
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obviously free the input as it can be a literal, some memory you don't control. That would cripple your function even more than now.

You could return the old value of `inputString` so you'd be able to free it if needed.

```
char *ReplaceSubStr(char **inputString, const char *from, const char *to)
{
    char *old_string = *inputString;
    ...
    return old_string;
}
```

The caller is responsible to free the contents of `old_string` if needed.

If not needed (we have to workaround the `char **` input by assigning a valid writable array to a pointer to be able to pass this pointer:

```
char input[]="hello world";
char *ptr = input;
ReplaceSubStr(&ptr, "hello", "hi");
// input is now "hi world" in a different location
free(ptr);  // when replaced string isn't needed
```

if needed:

```
char *input = strdup("hello world");
char *old_input = ReplaceSubStr(&input, "hello", "hi");
free(old_input);
```

or just

```
free(ReplaceSubStr(&input, "hello", "hi"));
```

then always (when replaced string isn't needed):

```
free(input);
```

The only constraint is that you cannot use a constant string literal as input (`const char *input = "hello world"`) because of the prototype & the possible return of a `char *` to pass to `free`.

Comment: correct. Fixed. The double pointer input is not very convenient when you want to pass literal/string constants.